# Should trialforce management org be the packaging org or a new org?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv, trialforce

I want to create a Trialforce Management Org (TMO) for our packages. One of our packages references the other package (core package) [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008uK1IAI) link suggests creating a new org and enabling it as a TMO but doesn't provide details or reasons. I think second packaging org as the TMO will save us the configuration required and want to go down that path. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should be new Org, a different from Packaging Org.

Comment: Here is the link which will help you to setup TMO, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/trialforce_conceptual_overview.htm?search_text=Trialforce

Comment: Thanks. We have done it in our packaging org in the past and didn't face any issues. I want to know why we should use a separate org and go through the process of configuring a new org.

Comment: Its just to avoid complexity that might increase in one org. A Devlopment team and TMO team can work independently in separate orgs.

Comment: @Devendra is correct, these really should be separate orgs so that you can maintain separation of duties and control. You do not want to have multiple users modifying your trunk packaging org metadata. Using a separate trailforce org allows you more fine grained environment controls.

Comment: Please be advised that: [Environment Hub](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Environment_Hub) would be a more simple solution for creating TSO orgs